# Naming convention: Adjective for linear operators that are endomorphisms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, terminology

If a matrix has the same number of rows and columns, we call it a square matrix. The analogous concept for linear operators would be operators with the same domain and range, i.e., endomorphisms.

Is there an **established** adjective that can be added to the word "operator" that denotes this concept?

In other words, what could I fill in for *xxx* in the following example sentence: "A square matrix is invertible iff it has full rank, but not every full-rank *xxx* operator is invertible."

**Note:** In many texts, "operator" already implies that domain and range are the same, but in some texts this is not assumed. Often, this distinction is left implicit. For example, "A course in functional analysis" (Conway 1990) considers bounded operators with different domain and range, while in what is basically the follow up book "A course in operator theory" (Conway 2000), bounded operators are assumed to have same domain and range.

---

**Short summary of suggestions**

- Endomorphic operator ([this comment](http://#comment842684_337124))
- Endo-operator or "... is endo" ([this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/337128/101775))
- Square operator (Textbook: [The Theory of Quantum Information](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI/), John Watrous)

Comment: Endomorphic? :-)

Comment: @M.G. I find very few mentions of "endomorphic operator" in Google. But if you can post your comment as an answer, people can comment more easily and we can get a feeling for the community opinion.

Comment: It was more of a joke since the immediate adjective from endomorphism would be endomorphic, but I don't think I've ever heard it being used like this (in mathematics anyway). To be honest, I doubt there is a widely used adjective for this, people just say "endomorphism of this or that". But on the other hand, if I ever see it used, then I'll most likely conclude that the author means an endomorphism.

Comment: I thought “operator” and “self-map” were basically synonyms. In other words, a linear map is a map between two vector spaces, while a linear operator is a map from a vector space to itself.

Comment: Wikipedia is a little unclear on this point: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)

Comment: See also: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map

Comment: @SamHopkins Convention differs between texts, unfortunately. I think, when the author is interested in studying operator algebras, then they will often assume that domain and range are the same (otherwise the set of operators will not form an algebra anyway). I added a note in the question.

Comment: Definitely using 'endomorphic' for the adjective form of 'endomorphism' will confuse people who work with automorphic forms.

Answer (score 4):

L. Kadison ([2012](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2902226), preprint [p. 8](//arxiv.org/abs/1110.1227)) uses ***endo-operator***. (That’s “[attributive](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression#Predicative_vs._attributive_adjectives)”, but I guess “predicative” use could still work, in the same way [MacLane](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=50:7275) says an arrow is *epi*.)

Comment: "Endo-operator" sounds very acceptable to me. (Not important here, but in the jargon I am familiar with, we say an arrow is *epic*, or that it is *an epi*, and not that an arrow "is epi". I cannot swear how universal this usage is, but if I found myself saying "is epi", I would regard it as a minor slip.)

Comment: When you refer to using this as an adjective, are you suggesting "the operator is endo" or "the endo operator" (no hyphen)?  Without that, this just seems to be a synonym for "endomorphism" (which is just "endo-morphism", after all).

Comment: @LSpice [Both](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression#Predicative_vs._attributive_adjectives) (and I agree with your point).

Answer (score 2):

In Operator Theory,  *an operator **on** the space $X$,* is quite commonly used to mean $T:X\to X$, denoting $L(X)$ or $B(X)$ the space of these operators in the same spirit.

*Self-map* is quite common for Discrete dynamical systems, so I guess *linear self-map* could do, even though a bit strange. *Self-operator* seems more natural, but I've never seen it.

Comment: But this is two nouns and a preposition, whereas the post asks for an adjective.  (For the noun, we already have 'endomorphism'.)

Comment: You're absolutely right, but the boldface character made me think that in the lack of a better word, *established* was somehow preferred to *adjective* :)